# How set height to spinner in action bar

Tags: android, listview, android-actionbar, android-spinner

I have dropdown list in action bar.

```
getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(
             new SomeAdapter(), 
             new ActionBar.OnNavigationListener() {...});
```

But when I add items to this list, they displayed not in the way, that I want to. If i set singleline for listitem, it will be cutted, like it is on first screen:

[image]

And if I won't set singleline, there will be scroll, even if I have a lot of space below this popup:

[image]

**So how can I force to show it correctly? At least without scroll, when i have enough space below.**

I can set height for each list item view, but I don't want to use custom values. I want use some styles or default values, in order to make it looks good for all versions and screen sizes.